# An issue when creating a pop-up menu w.r.t to a parametr via loop

Tags: c++, qt, menu, popup

I am trying to create pop-up menu depending on a variable as follows:

```
    QMenu menu(widget);
    for(int i = 1; i <= kmean.getK(); i++)
    {
        stringstream ss;
        ss << i;
        string str = ss.str();
        string i_str = "Merge with " + str;
        QString i_Qstr = QString::fromStdString(i_str);
        menu.addAction(i_Qstr, this, SLOT(mergeWith1()));
    }
    menu.exec(position);
```

**where:**

`kmean.get(K)` returns an `int` value,

```
mergeWith1() is some `SLOT()` which works fine
```

**Issue:**

The loop creates an action on menu only for **i=1** case, and ignores other values of `i`.

***Additional information***

When doing the same loop with casual `int` values (**without convert**) everything works fine. **e.g.**  if I do in loop only `menu.addAction(i, this, SLOT(...)))` and my **K=4**, a menu will be created with four actions in it, named 1, 2, 3, 4 correspondingly.

***What can be the problem caused by***

I think the issue is in convert part, when I convert `i` to `string` using `stringstream` and after to `QString`. **May be** the value is somehow lost. I am not sure.

**QESTION:**

- How to make the loop accept the convert part?
- What do I do wrong in convert part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In Qt code, you shouldn't be using `std::stringstream` or `std::string`. It's pointless.
2. You have a crashing bug by having the menu on the stack *and* giving it a parent. It'll be double-destructed.
3. Don't use the synchronous blocking methods like `exec()`. Show the menu asynchronously using `popup()`.
4. In order to react to the actions, connect a slot to the menu's `triggered(QAction*)` signal. That way you can deal with arbitrary number of automatically generated actions.
5. You can use the Qt property system to mark actions with custom attributes. `QAction` is a `QObject` after all, with all the benefits. For example, you can store your index in an "index" property. It's a dynamic property, created on the fly.

Here's a complete example of how to do it.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QAction>
#include <QMenu>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QPushButton>

struct KMean {
    int getK() const { return 3; }
};

class Widget : public QPushButton
{
    Q_OBJECT
    KMean kmean;
    Q_SLOT void triggered(QAction* an) {
        const QVariant index(an->property("index"));
        if (!index.isValid()) return;
        const int i = index.toInt();
        setText(QString("Clicked %1").arg(i));
    }
    Q_SLOT void on_clicked() {
        QMenu * menu = new QMenu();
        int last = kmean.getK();
        for(int i = 1; i <= last; i++)
        {
            QAction * action = new QAction(QString("Merge with %1").arg(i), menu);
            action->setProperty("index", i);
            menu->addAction(action);
        }
        connect(menu, SIGNAL(triggered(QAction*)), SLOT(triggered(QAction*)));
        menu->popup(mapToGlobal(rect().bottomRight()));
    }
public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = 0) : QPushButton("Show Menu ...", parent) {
        connect(this, SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(on_clicked()));
    }
};

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();
    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```